# Ng-select dropdown heroes and use the selected hero?

Tags: angular

on my fight.component.html i was listing all my heroes with ngFor. But now i want to do a dropdown via ng-select to select ONE hero on my frontend to use a method i will create.

```
<a *ngFor="let hero of heroes" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="heroElement">
      {{hero.name}}

    </a>
```

Since i saw ng-select and a few examples i cant really help myself and compare them with my idea.
this i what i currently have:

```
<ng-select [items]="heroes" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id" [(ngModel)]="chosenHero"></ng-select>
```

and my fight.component.ts:

```
  heroes: Hero[] = [];
  heroItems = [];
  chosenHero: Hero;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHeroes();

    this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(heroItems => this.heroes = this.heroItems);
  }

}
```

I kinda copied this line:

```
this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(heroItems => this.heroes = this.heroItems);
```

but i dont know what it does exactly. can someone give me some input which i can understand?

to sum up:
i want to pick via dropdown a hero from all my heroes i created in a previous site, then i kinda want the value of that picked hero to do things (methods like fighting with him another hero or villain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(heroItems => this.heroes = this.heroItems);
```

this line just gets all the heroes and stores them in the `heroItems` then you assign `this.heroes` with `this.heroItems` which is not the values from the service request. In typescript `this` **always** refers to a class variable.

So here you don't actually do anything with the new values. To do that remove this from the mentioned line.

To refer to new values

```js
this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(heroItems => this.heroes = heroItems);
```

New values stored in `this.heroes` and you could remove `heroItems = [];` and `getHeroes()`  function as is since this explained call does the same thing.

The chosen hero should be there in the `chosenHero` variable, it is handled through ngModel

Let me know if my answer was helpful or you have more questions :)

Comment: i dont really get the context:
how do i list all my heroes in my dropdown?
how do i get a selectedhero to my component.ts? which variable do i work with?
and what is the task behind the code u copied?

Comment: U said i dont do anything with my "new values" but how do i refer to my new values?

Comment: yea i understood. thank you. i compiled it and 
    <ng-select [items]="heroes" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id" [(ngModel)]="chosenHero"></ng-select>

just doesnt show on my website? do u know why?

Comment: I changed to <ng-select [items]="heroItems" but still it doesnt show any dropdown..

Comment: Change back to: `<ng-select [items]="heroes" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id" [(ngModel)]="chosenHero"></ng-select>
`

Comment: oh wait forgot what i said, it actually works, thank you buddy

Comment: yes i put in a placeholder, but it doesnt go away when i pick a hero, now i deleted the placeholder and the dropdown is gone... :/

Comment: Can you please give us more information on the new issue here?

Comment: i had to import the style.css of ngselect, its all good now thx!